# Using Javacscript parameter in Asp.net Code included in javascript function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here is my problem:

```
<script>
function processRequest(username, sessionToken, connectionId, processType,friendUser) {
    var request = { Username: username, Password: null, SessionToken: sessionToken, ConnectionId: connectionId, ProcessType: processType };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["APIURL"]/people/ProcessConnectRequest',
        data: request,
        datatype: "jsonp",
        success: function(result) {
            if (result === "PROCESSED") {
                $('#item_' + connectionId).remove();

                var htmlContent ='<div class="col-lg-4 gray-box">'
                            +'<div class="general-item-list" id="requestList">'
                              +  '<div class="item">'
                               +     '<div class="item-head">'
                                +        '<div class="item-details">'
                                 +        '@Html.Action("LoadPeopleStatus", "People", new { id ="abc"})'
                                +        '</div>'

                                 +   '</div>'
                              +  '</div>'
                           + '</div>'
                       + '</div>';

                $('#containerBox').append(htmlContent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I want to replace `id ="abc"` with `friendUser` parameter, but not success. Any idea?

Comment: You are mixing client-side logic with a server-side template. This is not work, ever.

Comment: Thank you, i'll change my code

Comment: try this `id =friendUser`

Answer (score 0):

The Html.Action will be rendered on the server long before the client receives the page, much less begins to process the script or execute the success callback (with the parameter you want to use).

Instead of building the HTML content to append to your container you could send it back as the result of your POST request, checking the status code instead of "PROCESSED" as your success indicator and append the result (which should have the content type "text/html") to your container.

Alternatively you could send back a JSON object with a status flag, and the HTML content as a separate property.

For simplicity I'd favor using the status code as your success indicator though, meaning you can simply append the response as received from the server.

Make sure you return the content as a [partial view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview.aspx) and not a view result (assumed to be a complete page) so it doesn't include the layout if you have one.

You will need to add friendUser as a parameter to your request unless it can be derived or inferred from one of your existing request parameters

**Edit**

Should you not be willing or able to change the API endpoint (although you should be able to use the [accepts header](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and/or the overload with the additional parameter to distinguish between the existing returns behavior and the new HTML response), you will need to make a second AJAX request in the success callback of the first (after establishing correct processing), passing the friendUser either as part of the URL or as a parameter. This could be a GET request and there would need to be to a controller action that would return the HTML from your action. It is likely an ideal candidate for server caching assuming it is some kind of status or profile widget. Given you will have the latency of two HTTP connections and the processing of the initial POST request to deal with you will want to make and return the widget as quickly as possible.

I'd suggest also returning a PartialView here, and placing the HTML that is currently within your script tag in that view, then rendering the Action in the appropriate place within that view using the friendUser data from your model/ViewData passed from the controller action.